# Rstudio IDE data viewer filter on numeric column issue

Tags: rstudio

I have some issue with the viewer pane in R studio: I can't filter numeric columns with a single value. Filtering with the bin selection on the hist works but if I type numbers in the text box beneath the hist nothing happens.

Can anybody help me?
Thanks

Info:

We have multiple dedicated containers of Rstudio on a Linux server (using Portainer). Only my container gets this issue, using another teammate container filter on table works perfectly. Same version of R and Rstudio:

R version: 3.6.1 (2019-07-05)
Rstudio version: Version 1.2.5019
OS: Linux